# How can I align dynamic column data with dynamic row data in an html table?

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

Right now, without the alignment, the data is displayed like this:

[image: Component rendered by browser]
The columns are called in a single variable as there are multiple excel tabs with different columns and in the other `tr` tag rows are checked to match with the particular columns.

---

**The HTML**

```
 <table class="styled-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr id="colNames">
                                <!-- Keep this table header because it makes the checkbox in its own column -->
                                <th>
                                </th>
                                <th *ngFor="let column of tabColumnsForTable">
                                    {{column}}
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let row of toDoTasks; let i = index" id="taskList" class="active-row">
                                <td class="divTd">
                                    <label>
                                        <mat-checkbox (change)="moveTabTaskToDone(row, i)"
                                            [(ngModel)]="checkboxesForToDo[i]">
                                        </mat-checkbox>
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.qty">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.qty}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.vendor">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.vendor}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.name_type">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.name_type}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.style">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.style}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.component">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.component}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.material">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.material}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.height">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.height}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.width">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.width}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.depth">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.depth}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.edgeBanding">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.edgeBanding}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.insetCarvings">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.insetCarvings}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.name">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.name}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.total_calc_area">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.total_calc_area}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.linears">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.linears}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.length">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.length}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.thickness">
                                    <td [ngClass]="{'crossOut': checkboxesForToDo[i]}">{{row.thickness}}</td>
                                </div>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Done">

                <mat-checkbox class="checkMarkAll" (change)="markAllTasksAsToDo()" [(ngModel)]="markAllToDo">
                    Mark all as to do
                </mat-checkbox>

                <div id="taskList">
                    <table class="styled-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr id="colNames">
                                <!-- Keep this table header because it makes the checkbox in its own column -->
                                <th>
                                </th>
                                <th *ngFor="let column of tabColumnsForTable">
                                    {{column}}
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let row of doneTasks; let i = index" id="taskList" class="active-row">
                                <td class="divTd">
                                    <label>
                                        <mat-checkbox (change)="moveTabTaskTo_ToDo(row, i)"
                                            [(ngModel)]="checkboxesForDone[i]">
                                        </mat-checkbox>
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.qty">
                                    <td>{{row.qty}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.vendor">
                                    <td>{{row.vendor}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.name_type">
                                    <td>{{row.name_type}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.style">
                                    <td>{{row.style}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.component">
                                    <td>{{row.component}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.material">
                                    <td>{{row.material}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.height">
                                    <td>{{row.height}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.width">
                                    <td>{{row.width}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.depth">
                                    <td>{{row.depth}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.edgeBanding">
                                    <td>{{row.edgeBanding}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.insetCarvings">
                                    <td>{{row.insetCarvings}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.name">
                                    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.total_calc_area">
                                    <td>{{row.total_calc_area}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.linears">
                                    <td>{{row.linears}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.length">
                                    <td>{{row.length}}</td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divTd" *ngIf="row.thickness">
                                    <td>{{row.thickness}}</td>
                                </div>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

**The CSS**
Referred from this link with some changes:

https://dev.to/dcodeyt/creating-beautiful-html-tables-with-css-428l

Comment: You really don’t want to mix divs with your table structure. Why not put the ngIf’s on the tr’s itself? Or use ng-container for those

Comment: You can use CSS Grid to define the `grid-template-columns` for the header and the rows as well, so they all have the same widths.

Be warned that for large tables, there can be some performance issues if you are using CSS Grid.

Comment: Those divs should be inside the `td` and the table cells should align on its own. Those are probably the reason why they are not aligning correctly

Comment: @RisingSun Placing those divs under the td element only aligns the rows which comes directly under that column header and as the columns are called in a single variable they just stay there and the rows skip that header as they are farther down in the html.

Comment: @KirtanParekh I am having a hard time understanding what you mean. Could you give a screenshot of the result and maybe a visual example of what the data should look like?

Comment: @RisingSun As this is an excel file I am retrieving there are multiple tabs and each tab has different columns. So I have an array that stores all the column name data and with those *ngIf I am checking the rows if it falls under that column. And as you said I got rid of the divs and used the condition in the <td> element. But still, it doesn't align the table rows with their appropriate columns.

Comment: @KirtanParekh In your browser using chrome developer tools check the rendered element tree. See if it is proper and no elements are missing. You can adjust styles there to see what is causing them not to align.

Answer (score 0):

Using `div` elements as direct children of `tr` is not allowed by the HTML standard ([as mentioned here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tr-element)). So I would suggest to try to generate a valid table (without `div` elements) by moving the `*ngIf` conditions directly on the `td` elements. Please see the example below:

```html
<table class="styled-table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="colNames">
      <th *ngFor="let column of tabColumnsForTable">
        {{column}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td *ngIf="false">one</td>
    <td *ngIf="true">two</td>
    <td *ngIf="false">three</td>
    <td *ngIf="true">four</td>
    <td *ngIf="false">five</td>
    <td *ngIf="true">six</td>
    <td *ngIf="true">seven</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In this example, `tabColumnsForTable` is defined as:

```
tabColumnsForTable = [
    "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4"
]
```

The result is:

[image]

As the `td` elements for the missing columns are skipped, all the rows should have the same number of columns as the header row and all of them should be automatically aligned.

**Later edit:** If the columns are still out of line, maybe the `ngIf` condition is not catching situations like: column should be displayed but has not data in a specific row. Then all the following columns will be displaced to the left by one position.

I would recommend to test if the `tabColumnsForTable` actually contains a specific column. `ngIf` would become:

```
<td *ngIf='tabColumnsForTable.includes("vendor")'>
    {{row.vendor}}
</td>
```

In this case, if `row.vendor` is empty/null but the column `vendor` is in the list, an empty table cell will be rendered and the correct table structure should be preserved.

Comment: tried doing this but doesn't work.

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: Remains the same.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include an example dataset for `tabColumnsForTable` and `doneTasks`? Having actual data will help us figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for here, you can achieve this using CSS.

To align the text in the center of a column, you can use CSS **text-align: center;** function, or the **align-items: center;** function too. If you want them to be dead center, of the column window, then use **align-items: center;** in combination with **justify-content: center;** !

Hope this helped. I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but this should be one way of fixing your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's a CSS issue, have been trying all of the different combinations to make this work but no luck.